# can't access constructor's context from $scope's event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

**How can I access NavService (i.e. or the controller's context)?**

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
        public static $inject = ['$scope', 'NavService'];
        constructor(private $scope: any, private NavService: MyWizard.NavService) {
            this.$scope.okCmd = this.okCmd;
        }
        okCmd() {
            this.NavService.next('details');
        }
}
```

Result: `NavService` is undefined because `this.` actually represents `$scope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a common problem in the JavaScript world, and that's why we will have function binding expressions in es7: `this.$scope.okCmd = ::this.okCmd;`

For now you can use a lambda that will store the constructor's `this` pointer in it's closure:

```
module MyModule {
  export class MyClass {
    public static $inject = ['$scope', 'NavService'];
    constructor(private $scope: any, private NavService: MyWizard.NavService) {
      this.$scope.okCmd = () => this.okCmd();
    }
    okCmd() {
      this.NavService.next('details');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation. even tho I kind of knew this, but still need tons of practice.